# Connect git local account to bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

When I commit in bitbucket the user git is not the same as my Bitbucket account .
The username on the commit is the same as my GitHub account.
How can I change my user to have the same name on bitbucket ?

I try to change the user name with git config — global user.name et user.email but nothing change

Comment: it wont change old commits, it would only have an effect for new commits going forward.  What is it giving you, what do you expect?   are there perhaps multiple gitconfig files getting in the way?  Usually you just put your name as the user.name and your email as the email and put the appropriate matching email in github/bitbucket/name_your_host_service and they take care of the rest. but ive not used bitbucket.. just throwing this out there in case it helps.